# How to use phonetic edit-text or Search-view in Android?

Tags: android, phonetics

Like, I will write using a English keyboard but in `EditText`/`SearchView` the font will become Phonetic [bangla]. How can I achieve this ?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6yMq.png)

Comment: Don't develop any code yet , i will start this project after confirm i can work it out .

Answer (score 1):

The process is called transliteration. There are libraries available that can do that. The [Google Translate](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/translate/v2) library is one such example.

I'm thinking:

1. Enter text in your edit text.
2. Send it to Library.
3. Show a loading indicator.
4. Receive the transliterated response from Library.
5. Set it in your edit text
6. Hide loading indicator.

Comment: Vinay Wadhwa, No i want it offline and real time . there must be a library that i don't find out .